# Avoid vViewGroup flickering in listView

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented an adapter in Android for adding Admob native ads into a LivtView object. It is a simple solution and it works fine but the native ad flickers when scrolling the list view. The flickering actually occurs when lifting my finger from the screen - while the list is scrolling the native ad scrolls with no flickering.

The way I do this is by inserting both regular listview items and native ads in the same adapter - I keep track of the positions where the native ads are inserted and I load native ads in the background - before ads are loaded, I insert a dummy View into the adapter; as each ad is loaded, I replace the dummy View with the native ad. On getView, I check if the item to draw is a native ad, and if so, I inflate a dummy LinearLayout view and do the following to add to it the native ad (if it has been loaded):

```
((ViewHolder) holder).layout.removeAllViews();
((ViewHolder) holder).layout.addView(view);
```

Is there an easy fix to this? I have seen solutions for similar cases when using a RecyclerView but I have not found a solution to this.

Comment: I suggest native admob is not wise choice for it, for feeds ads use NativeExpress Ads, also you need to switch to RecyclerView for better controls over your recyclable content.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I found out that the native ad was inserted into the ListView every time the getView function was getting called (even if it was visible). The problem was a bug in my getView code - the code to populate the items was called every time, even if the view passed to the function was not null. Fixing this solved the problem!